# Laravel Shared Hosting 404 Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Before i start, I need to mention that i am really beginner on laravel and web service things. 
I have working laravel web service on my localhost. I can reach it via **localhost/api/teachers**. I am getting JSON data as i wanted with no problem.

Now i need to upload my laravel web service to use it from host. I am getting "404 Error". I couldn't figure it out whats wrong. I have tried few things to solve it but didn't work.

Here is my laravel settings.

**.htdocs**
[image: .htdocs settings]

**index.php**
[image: index.php settings]

**routes.php**
[image: route::settings]

All of my laravel files at host under "/public_html/app/**here**"

I have changed .env file settings properly. This might be a silly mistake by me but i am very beginner.

Comment: are you accessing your route throug http://yourdomain.com/app/here/public/?
tell us a bit more of the structure of the laravel project.
did you run composer update?

Comment: As I said I am beginner. Normally on my local laravel, I can reach it via localhost/api/teachers. Now Im trying to reach it my domain.com/app/api/teachers.  am i being silly

Comment: There is literally no point of using a shared hosting while you can buy a cloud for 5$ per month. (ex. DigitalOcean)

Answer (score 0):

I asume for being a shared hosting your domain is set to public_html/ so your laravel project is somethig like this

public_html
    app/
       app/
       public/
       ...

when you make a request to you laravel project, it normally would go to `public/` folder, so if that's the folder structure then your request should go to

```
yourdomain.com/app/public/api/teachers
```

Comment: Now I have different error which is nice. I have SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_name'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES). But I granted all privileges through channel user.

Comment: the first problem is solved, know that means the user or password are wrong, or that the user have no privileges